# Can Timer Triggers call Activity Triggers in Azure?

Tags: function, email, triggers, azure-durable-functions, azure-triggers

I am creating a timer trigger function that is going to do certain checks. If a certain conditional is hit, I want to send an email and have set this up through an Activity Trigger. I keep getting the error

```
The function 'activityTriggerName` doesn't exist', additional info: No orchestrator functions are currently registered!.
```

I am brand new to durable functions and triggers in Azure, any direction on if this is allowed or other ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Activity functions can only be initiated by an Orchestrator. The usual pattern is to have a trigger function create an orchestrator and then the orchestrator initiates one or more activity functions.

If you’re using Visual Studio then the Orchestrator template will create a sample which includes an HTTP trigger, an orchestrator and an activity.